# Javascript find object with matching property in array of objects and get another property if exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm looking for an elegant solution to this the following:

In many places of my code, I need to find an object that matches an id in an array of objects and then return a property on that object.  The referenced id **may or may not exist** in the array.

The shortest solution I have come up with is the following:

(wanting to get the title of an item if the item exists, otherwise return none)

```
arrayofObjects = [ { id: 'a3ff3d', title: 'Tesla', color: 'Red' }, { id: 'r43wesd', title: 'AMC', color: 'Rust' }]
wantedObject = { queryTitle: 'Desired Car', id: 'a3ff3d' }


let wantedProperty = arrayOfObjects.some( e => e.id === wantedObject.id) ? arrayOfObjects.find(e => e.id === wantedObject.id).title : 'None Found'
```

However, this is neither elegant or as efficient as it should be.  I'd prefer for it to be a one liner instead of a function.

Comment: You should provide some sample data and expected result. You should be able to use *find* once, not *some* + *find*. It should return a useful value like *undefined* or *null* that other processes can use rather than a random string.

Comment: "one-liner" and "efficient" don't really go hand-in-hand a lot of times. You'll always get more performance out of a normal `for` loop than `Array.prototype` methods.

Comment: Just go for `(array.find(…) || {}).title`

Comment: Example data added.  Yes, I am thinking that I should be able to use find once, but I'm struggling on how to write it.  Returning undefined or null would be acceptable.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not true, native array methods are [just as fast](https://youtu.be/EhpmNyR2Za0?t=17m15s) as `for` loops.

Comment: @Bergi nice dead link

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Dammit. It was a video about a V8 internals talk. I'll try to find it somewhere else

Comment: Personally, I'm going more for readability and understanding then for speed.  It just seems like I shouldn't need to first do a check to see if it's there and then do another check to extract the information.  I'm looking to do one function call which searches and returns the data if it exists.  Bergi's solution is nice, but isn't exactly easily understood.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not convinced that callbacks passed to native array methods will _always_ be inlined, whereas a `for` loop will never have the overhead of function invocation on each iteration. And even if you do find a talk about v8 internals, that's _one_ implementation, and only a relatively recent development, I'm sure, since I've seen plenty of benchmarks in the past demonstrating consistent and significant performance improvements by switching from array methods to equivalent `for` loops.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts [This](https://youtu.be/m9cTaYI95Zc?t=951) is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Bergi your link discusses `for...of` loops, which is syntactic sugar for using [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) methods, and have comparable overhead to other `Array.prototype` methods. I'm talking about plain old `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` loops...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The speaker specifically calls out "*The good news today is that whether you want to use `forEach`, or write your own `for` loop, or use `for … of`, performance-wise it doesn't matter any more.*".

Comment: @Bergi I'm sure I'll get grief about the contrived example here, but regardless, [I'm still not convinced](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-for-of-vs-find).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The smallest method is not necessarily the most efficient. I would do it this way:

```
let wantedProperty = (arrayOfObjects.find(obj => obj.id === wantedObject.id) || {}).title || 'None Found';
```

Comment: I think if you replace *e* with a more meaningful variable name like *obj* or similar it will be much clearer, e.g. `obj.id == wantedObj.id`. :-)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their suggestions!  Bergi actually suggested this exact approach as a comment to the original question and I liked it.  Accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array#find and destructuring.

```js
const data = [ { id: 'a3ff3d', title: 'Tesla', color: 'Red' }, { id: 'r43wesd', title: 'AMC', color: 'Rust' }];

function search(idToFind){
  const res = data.find(({id}) => id === idToFind);
  return res ? res.title : "Nothing found";
}


console.log(search('r43wesd'));
console.log(search('fail'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can create a one line, generalized method for your data structure that you can reuse multiple times:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
    {id: 'a3ff3d', title: 'Tesla', color: 'Red'},
    {id: 'r43wesd', title: 'AMC', color: 'Rust'}
];

const getKey = (a, id, key) => (f = a.find(x => x.id === id)) ? f[[key]] : "Not Found";

console.log(getKey(arrayOfObjects, "a3ff3d", "title"));
console.log(getKey(arrayOfObjects, "r43wesd", "color"));
console.log(getKey(arrayOfObjects, "someid", "color"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I thought of 2 possible solution. First the one I do NOT recommend:

```
array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return cur.id == searchedId ? cur.title : acc;
}, "None found");
```

Especially if you need to use it frequently, avoid "complex" code, even if we are considering one line.

The second option (if you do not really want to use a function) is this one:

```
Array.prototype.findOrElse = function(cb, objcb, retValue) {
    let findElem = this.find(elem => cb(elem));

    return objcb(findElem) || retValue;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
array.findOrElse(elem => elem.id == searchedId, elem => elem.title, "None found");
```

Generally I do not choose this way because I prefer not to touch native objects that js provides, but no one forbids it.

---

EDIT:
 As @PatrickRoberts made me notice, this is not really an answer. I just found 2 possible solutions that for different reasons I do not recommend. Functions have this advantage: you do not have to repeat the same code, even if it is one line. Think about a possible situation where you may have to retrieve a different property instead of `title`.

On the other hand, customize a function inside the prototype of `Array` object is difficult: you try to make that function as generic as possible, with the risk of excessively complicating the function definition.

So why not going with your own defined function?

Comment: I find the second suggestion to be  very convoluted. Not my downvote though.

Comment: I don't believe `elem.id == {searchedId}` will ever evaluate to `true` either.

Comment: @RobG I do agree and I specified that I do not use that. It is convoluted but it is flexible and if he prefers not to use a function, better the second option than using the same complex piece of code multiple times.

Comment: Did you mean `elem.id == searchedId`? Same for `cur.id == {searchedId}`, you probably meant `cur.id == searchedId`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, I did. It's like a placeholder, nothing that belongs to js.

Comment: Your placeholder is valid syntax that is shorthand in ES6 for an anonymous object `{ searchedId: searchedId }`, so it's very misleading if you meant that to be `your_search_id_here`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am aware of that but I thought It was clear enough for this simple  code. I was probably wrong. Now I edit, Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Either way you look at it, your answer consists of two approaches, both of which you recommend against using. So I'm not sure what information you intend readers to take away... "Don't use either of these"? That doesn't really seem like an answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts—I think it's a valid answer, just not one I'd vote for. :-)